# Keep state in Stepper

Tags: flutter

I have multiple steps in my Stepper. How do I persist the state of the Step when moving between each Step?

I have tried adding the AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin, but it still does not keep the state:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<MyHomePage> {
  int currentStep = 0;
  List<Step> stepList = [
    Step(
      title: Text("Page A"),
      content: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("Page A"),
          TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: InputBorder.none,
              hintText: "Enter anything"
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
    ),
    Step(
      title: Text("Page B"),
      content: Text("Page B")
    ),
    Step(
      title: Text("Page C"),
      content: Text("Page C")
    ),
    Step(
      title: Text("Page D"),
      content: Text("Page D")
    ),
    Step(
      title: Text("Page E"),
      content: Text("Page ")
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stepper(
        steps: stepList,
        type: StepperType.horizontal,
        currentStep: currentStep,
        onStepContinue: nextStep,
        onStepCancel: cancelStep,
      ),
    );
  }

  void nextStep(){
    setState(() {
      if(currentStep < stepList.length - 1)
        currentStep++;
    });
  }

  void cancelStep(){
    setState(() {
      if(currentStep > 0)
      currentStep--;
    });
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

If I add anything to the text field, navigate to PageB, then navigate back to PageA, the text field would reset to empty back.

How do I keep state for each Step's "page"?

Edit:
Probably should've disclosed this earlier. I have 5 Steps, with each Step containing 8-12 fields consisting of textfields, checkboxes, dropdowns, etc. It's a multi step form. I know you can create a class level TextFieldController to have a "global" variable to keep track of the TextField's state in the Step, but it would mean I need ~50 class level variables, the code would look too convoluted. That is why I was using AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin, but it doesn't work. Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Can you please provide some more details, your question is not clear.

Comment: Thanks for the question, I hope you have founded a proper solution but your question solved my problem

Answer (score 4):

What's happening is your `TextField` is getting rebuild when you are navigating to it from another `Step` and so value is getting reset.

Solution:

1. Convert your `List<Step>` to `get` that returns `List<Step>` like `List<Step> get stepList => [`
2. Reason to do this is to make your list able to access global variables.
3. Create a `TextEditingController` as global variable: `TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();`
4. Give that controller to your `TextField` like follows:

   ```
     TextField(
       controller: textEditingController,
       decoration: InputDecoration(
         border: InputBorder.none,
         hintText: "Enter anything"
       ),
     ),
   ```

Now what will happen is that as you have the `TextEditingController` , whenever your `TextField` will rebuild it will use the controller to get the value so, whenever you are switching between `Step`s your `TextField` value won't reset.

I have edited your code, following is the code with the above mentioned changes:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<MyHomePage> {
  int currentStep = 0;

  TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();

  List<Step> get stepList => [
    Step(
      title: Text("Page A"),
      content: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("Page A"),
          TextField(
            controller: textEditingController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: InputBorder.none,
              hintText: "Enter anything"
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
    ),
    Step(
      title: Text("Page B"),
      content: Text("Page B")
    ),
    Step(
      title: Text("Page C"),
      content: Text("Page C")
    ),
    Step(
      title: Text("Page D"),
      content: Text("Page D")
    ),
    Step(
      title: Text("Page E"),
      content: Text("Page ")
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stepper(
        steps: stepList,
        type: StepperType.horizontal,
        currentStep: currentStep,
        onStepContinue: nextStep,
        onStepCancel: cancelStep,
      ),
    );
  }

  void nextStep(){
    setState(() {
      if(currentStep < stepList.length - 1)
        currentStep++;
    });
  }

  void cancelStep(){
    setState(() {
      if(currentStep > 0)
      currentStep--;
    });
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

I hope this helps you, in case of any doubt please comment. *In case this answer helps you, please accept and up-vote it.*

Comment: The problem with doing this is if I have 8-10 fields per page, and I have 5 pages, I would need 50 class variables, it looks very convoluted. Surely there must be a better way?

Comment: If you have 8-10 fields per page then create a separate widget that has Textfield and TextEditingController in it and use that Widget everywhere..

Comment: Thanks, you saved a lot of time for me.

Comment: Is there a way to maintain image state? I am loading an image on button click but when I move to next step and come back the state is rebuilt and image is gone.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `TextEditingController()`

code snippet

```
 TextEditingController _pageA = TextEditingController();

 Step(
        title: Text("Page A"),
        content: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("Page A"),
            TextField(
              controller: _pageA,
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TextEditingController _pageA = TextEditingController();
  int currentStep = 0;
  List<Step> stepList;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    stepList = [
      Step(
        title: Text("Page A"),
        content: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("Page A"),
            TextField(
              controller: _pageA,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none, hintText: "Enter anything"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        state: StepState.indexed,
      ),
      Step(title: Text("Page B"), content: Text("Page B")),
      Step(title: Text("Page C"), content: Text("Page C")),
    ];
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageA.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stepper(
          steps: stepList,
          type: StepperType.horizontal,
          currentStep: currentStep,
          onStepContinue: nextStep,
          onStepCancel: cancelStep,
          onStepTapped: (step) {
            setState(() {
              currentStep = step;
            });
          }),
    );
  }

  void nextStep() {
    setState(() {
      if (currentStep < stepList.length - 1) currentStep++;
    });
  }

  void cancelStep() {
    setState(() {
      if (currentStep > 0) currentStep--;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem with doing this is if I have 8-10 fields per page, and I have 5 pages, I would need 50 class variables, it looks very convoluted. It would also violate the principle of having variable as local as possible (having it at class level, even though I only really needed to keep track of Step, not the parent's)

Comment: you can use List<TextEditingController>

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to use the AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin with the actual widget that has the stepper rather than your steps widget.
That way each step is preserved as you navigate between screens

Comment: And you could store the values in a reusable ViewModel class shared between screens to reinitialise the value when the widget rebuilds